# Left join with other table with where clause

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have 2 tables in MySQL database that I would like to join, where I would like to contain all results from table1.

My tables looks like this:

`table1`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 5 | name5 |
| 6 | name6 |
| 7 | name7 |
| 8 | name8 |

`table2`

| id | table1_id | myfield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | test1 |
| 2 | 2 | test2 |
| 3 | 1 | test1 |
| 4 | 4 | test2 |
| 5 | 5 | null |
| 6 | 2 | null |

What I am trying to achieve is to get a table which contains all the rows from `table1` and only the data that is joined from `table2`.

This is my query:

```
select * from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
where myfield="test1"
group by t1.id
```

But this is not what I want to achieve.

What I want to achieve is to get all records from `table1` and to have all related records from `table2` where `table2.myfield="test1"`. And for the other for `table2.mytable` to have null (if they do not fulfil `table2.myfield="test1"`).

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: *`where myfield="test1"`* converts your LEFT joining to INNER. Move the condition by right table from WHERE to ON clause.

Comment: [tag:mysql] <> [tag:sql-server] which one are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
select * from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
and myfield="test1"
group by t1.id
```

BTW: some DBMS does not allow `select *`  with `group by`. So select the `id` and some aggregated values or remove `group by id`

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!